# AlarmManager from service

Tags: android, alarmmanager

i have a background Service which starts and AlaramManager. 
i've logged when the AlarmManager fires and see that it only fires when the application has no activities running and the only thing that runs is the background Service..
why is that ?

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (app.isApplicationInitilized())
    {
        //stopAlarmManager();
        server.start();
        startAlarmManager();            
    }
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}


public void startAlarmManager()
{       
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (10*1000), 10*1000, alarmPendingIntent);
}

private void setAlarmManager() {
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmManagerReceiver.class);       
    alarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 8258, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

}
```

Comment: It depends who is receiver of your pending intent. If receiver is some class and you register it only in code inside service, then alarm will work only if service was running and registetered receiver. You should try to register alarm receiver in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: but the code i've written above is run when the service is starting.. the service works when the activity is running and when it doesn't.. how can i register it in the manifest ?

Comment: some info on this would be helpful: alarmPendingIntent

Comment: Show what's in the `alarmPendingIntent` (how you are creating it).