# Calling AlarmManager in Service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

**Context:** I am attempting to implement one service call a second service (a subclass of the first) via an AlarmManager. To do this, I needed to create a Broadcast Receiver as an inner class, as recommended here ([Service and a BroadCastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958800/service-and-a-broadcastreceiver)). However, it appears that the first service is never successfully calling the second service, or the second service is not receiving the call.

I have looked around SO and found that someone else had a similar problem that was never resolved: [AlarmManager from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664523/alarmmanager-from-service).

The code in the first service to call the second is simply:

```
private final long ONE_MINUTE = 60*1000*1;

 Context theContext = getBaseContext(); 
    AlarmManager theService = (AlarmManager) theContext
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent i = new Intent(theContext, LocalWordSubClass.class);

    PendingIntent thePending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(theContext, 0, i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    //call this after two minutes 
    theService.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+TWO_MINUTES, thePending);
```

My second service is:

```
public class LocalWordSubClass extends LocalWordService {
BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(checkIfGooglePlay() && checkTime()) {
            getPostLocation();
        }
        mLocationClient.disconnect(); //connected in the first service class
        stopSelf();
    }
};
```

}

My manifest with second service recognized:

```
<service
        android:name=".LocalWordSubClass"
        android:label="LocalWordSubClass" >
    </service>
```

**Question:** Am I failing to implement a method? Or did I need to add the Broadcast Receiver to the Manifest? I am a bit confused as to why the second class is not being responsive.

**UPDATE: ** Thanks to CommonWare's multiple recommendations, I was able to achieve this one-minute elapse between connecting the LocationClient and getting its last location. However, the service is no longer running on repeat, when called upon by the MainActivity's AlarmManager's setRepeating Method.

This is the code (that is successfully giving the locationClient time to connect)

```
 if(mLocationClient==null) {
    pm = (PowerManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
    wl.acquire();
        initalizeLocks();
        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
    mLocationClient.connect();
        Context theContext = getBaseContext();

    AlarmManager theService = (AlarmManager) theContext
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent i = new Intent(LocalWordService.this, this.getClass());

    PendingIntent thePending = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    //call this after two minutes 
    theService.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + ONE_MINUTE, thePending);
    } else {
        getPostLocation();
        wl.release();
        mLocationClient = null;
        stopSelf();
    }
```

The MainActivity's AlarmManager is:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalWordService.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarm.
    setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), EVERY_TWO_MINUTES, pintent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I failing to implement a method?

Well, `LocalWordSubClass` seems to be devoid of methods, other than inherited ones.

Also, you are attempting to send a broadcast `Intent` to a `Service` (via your `PendingIntent`), which is not going to work.

And, the `BroadcastReceiver` you have defined in `LocalWordSubClass` is unused.

Next, from [your related comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368540/do-i-need-to-use-an-alarmmanager-and-wakelock-to-periodically-use-a-locationclie/17370089?noredirect=1#comment25317973_17370089):

> I have the initial service call a new subclass (which has access to the LocationClient) after a two minute period

Your "new subclass" will have its own `mLocationClient`, unrelated to any `mLocationClient` from any other `Service` in your process.

You appear to be attempting to implement something I wrote about in [the preceding comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368540/do-i-need-to-use-an-alarmmanager-and-wakelock-to-periodically-use-a-locationclie/17370089?noredirect=1#comment25214626_17370089):

> @jsc123: "How would you recommend I give my LocationClient a two minute window to connect before polling the location?" -- you could just use AlarmManager, calling set() to get control in two minutes.

What I meant by that was that you would use `set()` on `AlarmManager` with a `getService()` `PendingIntent` to deliver control back to your already-running `Service` with its already-acquired `WakeLock`, so that it can obtain the location, release the `WakeLock`, and `stopSelf()`.

Comment: @CommmonsWare, I am still unsure of how to implement your recommendation. Even if I were to alter the PendingIntent to a getService (looking like this: Intent i = new Intent(theContext, LocalWordService.class);
  PendingIntent thePending = PendingIntent.getService(theContext, 0, i,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);) I don't understand how the service would receive the call, and moreover how I could avoid a recursive-deathtrap, in which a service would always be running.

Comment: To be clearer, I am unsure of how to have the service recognize when two minutes elapses, since there is no onReceive() method. For in that method, or something similar, I would need to use the location, disconnect the client, release the wakelock, and then kill the service.

Comment: @jsc123: "I don't understand how the service would receive the call" -- it will be called with `onStartCommand()`, as you can tell by reading the documentation for `getService()` on `PendingIntent`: http://goo.gl/f3hW3

Comment: I am aware of that. I mean I am unsure of how to distinguish a self-referential call in order to access the Location information, and a call from my Main telling the service to initiate the one-minute timer.

Comment: @jsc123: If you have a non-`null` `LocationClient`, access the location, then set the data member to `null`. If you have a `null` `LocationClient`, initialize the client and set your timer.

Comment: Thank you so much for all this. Now that this is finally working, my MainActivity's periodic calls no longer exist :(